# Help in understanding how to evaluate line integrals.

Tags: vector-analysis, line-integrals

I'm attempting to teach myself some vector calculus before starting university next month in hope of getting my head around some of the concepts as I can foresee this being a weak topic for me.

I have been 'learning' from some online lecture notes related to my course. The notes talk about line integrals but as far as I understand say little on how to evaluate them and only gives one quick example in the form below that I didn't find terribly useful. As a result I'm not entirely sure how to evaluate the line integral below and so I would ask that someone answer the below question, but if possible perhaps give more detail than would usually be necessary, talking through each step with a specific emphasis on the difference between evaluating (i) and (ii), thank you.

> Evaluate explicitly the line integral $\int(y$ $dx+x$ $dy+dz)$ along
>   (i) the straight path from the origin to $x=y=z=1$ and (ii) the
>   parabolic path given parametrically by $x = t,y = t,z = t^2$ from $t=0$ to
>   $t=1$.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the parabolic path is exactly. Did check the formulae?

Comment: This is jumping ahead a little bit, but the integrand is conservative, so the value of the line integral depends only on the endpoints of the path, not the path itself. This means that you should get the same answer for the integral along both parts. This also gives you another way to evaluate the integrals: find a scalar function $F(x,y,z)$ such that $\nabla F=(y,x,1)$ and then evaluate $F(1,1,1)-F(0,0,0)$.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks. Actually the notes touch more on that than they do on questions like the above.

Comment: Note that to check if a function $F$ as @amd tells you to find exists, given the integral $\int\left(Adx + Bdy + Cdz\right)$ the necessary and sufficient condition is $\frac{dA}{dy}-\frac{dB}{dx} = 0, \frac{dA}{dz}-\frac{dC}{dx} = 0, \frac{dB}{dz}-\frac{dC}{dy} = 0$ (assuming smooth functions A, B, C)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick mainly consists of parameterizing the curve $C$ in some parameter $t \in [0,1]$ and then you integrate
$$
\int_C f(x,y,z) = \int_0^1 f(x(t), y(t), z(t))
       \sqrt{|x'(t)|^2 + |y'(t)|^2 + |z'(t)|^2}dt.
$$

Let's do the first one together. The parameterization is obvious $x=y=z=t$ with $t \in [0,1]$, so $dx=dy=dz=dt$ and the integral becomes
$$
\int_C(ydx + xdy + dz) = \int_0^1 (tdt + tdt + dt) = \int_0^1 (2t+1)dt = \left. t^2 + t \right|_0^1 = 2.
$$
Please do the second one yourself.

Comment: @BobbieD thanks changing

Comment: So, if I'm understanding right we already have our parametrisation for (ii), we have $dx=dy=dt, dz=2t$ $dt$, so $\int_C(y$ $dx+x$ $dy+dz)=\int^1_0(t$ $dt+t$ $dt+2t$ $dt)=\int^1_04t$ $dt=[2t^2]^1_0=2$?

Comment: @user307463 i did not check the arithmetic, but the idea is correct

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. I'm almost certain this was not even touched upon in the notes, although perhaps I could have seen to do this myself.

Comment: @user307463 it helps to see one example done end to end. The trick most of the time is to choose the easy parameterization of the curve...

Answer (score 3):

You have to make a substitution with the parameter. I'll denote paths under the generic name $\gamma$.

For the first  integral, the parametrisation of the straight line is clearly $\;\begin{cases}x=t\\y=t\\z=t\end{cases}\enspace(0\le t\le 1)$, so $\;\mathrm d\mkern1mux=\mathrm d\mkern1mut=\mathrm d\mkern1muy=\mathrm d\mkern1muz $, and
$$\int_\gamma(y\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu x+x\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu y+\mathrm d\mkern1muz)=
\int_0^1(t\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu t+t\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu t+\mathrm d\mkern1mu t)=\int_0^1(2t+1)\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu t= t^2+t\,\bigg\vert_0^1=2.$$

Comment: I looked at your code, and I have to ask: What the heck does "\mkern1mu" do?

Comment: It's math kerning – a very small separation between the differential symbol and the variable (in normal latex, I'd use a macro, of course). 1mu (mathematical unit) is 1/18 em.

Comment: @Lovsovs you can escape your code to make it more readable, like this: `\mkern1mu`

Answer (score 3):

The path $C$ is parametrized as $\mathbf r(t) = t\mathbf x + t\mathbf y + t\mathbf z$ for $t\in[0,1]$.  Then you use the line integral formula

$$\int_{C} \mathbf f\cdot d\mathbf r = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \mathbf f(\mathbf r)\cdot \mathbf r'(t)\ dt$$

In this case $\mathbf f(\mathbf r)\cdot \mathbf r'(t) = (t\mathbf x + t\mathbf y + 1\mathbf z)\cdot(1\mathbf x + 1\mathbf y + 1\mathbf z) = 2t+1$.

Thus your line integral reduces to the Riemann integral

$$\int_0^1 [2t+1]\ dt$$

which is pretty easy to evaluate.

Comment: arithmetic does not work out, should be $2$, not $1$ in the end... feels like the final integral should be $\int_0^1 (2t+1)dt$

Comment: @gt6989b Thanks.  Fixed.